# PHP not executing commands

Tags: gpio, php, apache-httpd

I have an apache web server installed in my Raspberry Pi. I created an `index.php` file on the `/var/www/html` folder. Whenever I access my Pi's IP address on a web browser to control the lights, none of my commands seem to work after I press the buttons.

My `index.php` file is as follows:

```
<html>
<head>
<?php

shell_exec("gpio -g  mode 4 out");

$btn1 = exec('gpio -g read 4');


if(isset($_POST['l1'])) {
    if($btn1 == 1) {
        shell_exec("gpio -g write 4 0");
    }
    else {
        shell_exec("gpio -g write 4 1");
    }
}
?>

<title> LIGHT DEMO CONTROLS</title>
</head>

<body style= "background-color: rgb(0,44,165);" align = "center"><br><font size = "10" face = "Segoe UI" color = "white"><center>
LIGHT CONTROLS<br> <LIGHT CONTROLS<br>--</center></font><br><form method = "post">
    <table style = "width:600px; margin-left: auto; 
    margin-right: auto;margin-top: auto; margin-bottom: auto;"
    border = "2" cellpadding = "2" cellspacing = "2">
    <tbody>
<tr style = "text-align: center;">
    <td style = "text-align: center;"><font size = "10" face = "Segoe UI" color = "white"> L I G H T S</font></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<table style = "text-alight: center; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" 
border = "0" cellpadding = "10" cellspacing = "2">
<tbody>
<tr style = "text-align: center;">
    <td style = "text-align: center;"> <font size = "6" face =  "Segoe UI" color = "white"> Light 1</font></td>
    <td style = "text-align: center;"><button style =   "height:100px;width:150px" name= "l1"><font size ="6" face  = "Segoe UI" color = "black"> On/Off </font></button></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Basics: did you install the php module for apache? Then, does `/var/log/apache2/error.log` say anything when you go to your web page?

Comment: You will need to use `sudo usermod -G -a www-data gpio` to allow Apache2/Lighttpd/NGinx to run that `gpio` command.

Answer (score 1):

This is debug 101: don't bite more than you can chew. Make sure a single command works before debugging the complete app.

- Check the output of `shell_exec` for error messages.
- If there's nothing, add `2>&1` to your commands to also catch the output from STDERR.
- Still nothing? Replace `shell_exec` by `exec` and check the return code.
- You may also want to run a trivial command for a start (e.g. `df`) to see if your Apache/PHP setup works at all.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue using python, Executing shell script in PHP, etc. So the solution is:
`Application Menu` > `Preferences` > `Raspberry Pi Configuration` > `Interfaces` > `Enable Remote GPIO`.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question, although using remote gpio is better than trying to get a webserver running the `gpio` command from wiringPi. But that would need the person asking the question to change his/her code.

Answer (score 0):

Try shell scripting inside `shell_exec`, as

```
echo 1 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio4/value
```

For writing.